# Grails + log4j:ERROR WARNING: Exception occured configuring log4j logging: No such property: delegate for class: java.lang.String

Tags: tomcat, grails, logging, log4j

When I deploy my application on tomcat live, I get exception:
`log4j:ERROR WARNING: Exception occured configuring log4j logging: No such property: delegate for class: java.lang.String`

How can I solve it?
Here is the output of `catalina.out`

```
==> /data/logs/tomcat/catalina.out <==
Feb 22, 2016 5:05:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[ExternalConfigLoader] INFO: File /data/conf/admin-conf.groovy
[ExternalConfigLoader] INFO: File /data/conf/my.properties
[ExternalConfigLoader] INFO: File /data/conf/check_log4j.groovy
7.791: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 0K(3072000K)] 1148855K(5760000K), 0.0958523 secs] [Times: user=0.56 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs] 
7.887: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
7.889: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.002/0.002 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
7.889: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
7.893: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.005/0.005 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
7.893: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
log4j:ERROR WARNING: Exception occured configuring log4j logging: No such property: delegate for class: java.lang.String

==> /data/logs/tomcat/catalina.2016-02-22.log <==
22-Feb-2016 17:05:10.530 INFO [servername-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `check_log4j.groovy` contained logging setting not compatible with `Config.groovy`'s log4j config. OR the `check_log4j.groovy` is trying to override the log4j config in `Config.groovy`.

Detail:

**Config.groovy**

```
// Logging
final String catalinaBase = System.getProperty("catalina.base", "target")
final String logPattern = '%d [%t] %p %n\t%c.%M([...]) at Line %L %n%m%n%n'

// log4j configuration
log4j.main = {
    appenders {
        console(
                name: 'stdout',
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: logPattern)
        )
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                name: 'appLog',
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: logPattern),
                file: "${catalinaBase}/logs/appName/appName.log".toString()
        )
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                name: 'stacktrace',
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: logPattern),
                file: "${catalinaBase}/logs/appName/stacktrace.log".toString()
        )
    }
    root {
        additivity = true
        if (Environment.getCurrent().equals(Environment.PRODUCTION)) {
            warn 'appLog', 'stacktrace'
        } else {
            warn 'stdout', 'appLog'
        }
    }
    error 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    info 'com.example.appName'
}
```

**check_log4j.groovy**

```
log4j {
    rootLogger="DEBUG,stdout"

    appender.stdout = "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"
    appender."stdout.layout"="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
    appender."stdout.layout.conversionPattern"="%-p - %m%n"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your **grails.config.locations**: if you keep your config file in *.properties* type file, than change it to *.groovy* type.